# .lit reader for Linux

Tags: software-rec, ebooks

Is there any reader for ebooks in .lit format for Linux? Or is there one for Windows that I can run on my Linux with Wine?

Distro: openSUSE 12.2 x86_64 and Linux Mint 12 x86_64

Comment: I tried Microsoft Reader. It doesn't work. Unfortunately I am not aware of any other .lit readers for Windows either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [`calibre`](http://calibre-ebook.com/) for DRM-free ebooks.

Comment: Calibre can also convert .lit to other formats including epub, which can then be edited/cleaned-up with Sigil (or any text editor since an epub is just xhtml + css + iimages + toc etc in a zip file).  Sigil is packaged for debian and other distros.  Source is at http://code.google.com/p/sigil/ - IIRC the Sigil author also contributes to the Calibre project.

Answer (score 3):

[ConvertLit](http://www.convertlit.com/) or `clit` can convert .lit files to HTML.  If you have the DRM key file it can even convert DRM-restricted .lit files to HTML.

There is also a wrapper around convlit and zip called `lit2epub` which converts .lit to .epub.  It is in the `epub-utils` package on debian, or source code is at http://sourceforge.net/projects/ebook-tools

In most cases (i.e. non-DRM), using Calibre for ebook format conversion is much easier.